# How can I get dates given the name of the day of the week in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, date, datetime

Suppose I have the name of the day of the week like `'Wednesday'` or `'Monday'`, is there a way to get the dates of a month returned related to the given day of the week?

For instance in the given calendar below, is there a way to get the dates `[2,9,16,23,30]` for the day of 'Wednesday' in September 2020? The solution doesn't have to exactly match this as long as it returns the proper dates for the given day:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a go with this

```js
const dayNames = "Sunday,Monday,Tuesday,Wednesday,Thursday,Friday,Saturday".split(","),
  days = [...Array(32).keys()].splice(1); // generate 1-31
const getDates = (yyyy, mm, dayName) => {
  const dayNumber = dayNames.indexOf(dayName);
  mm -= 1; // JS months start at 0
  return days.filter(d => {
    const date = new Date(yyyy, mm, d);
    return mm === date.getMonth() && dayNumber === date.getDay()
  });
};

console.log(
  getDates(2020, 9, "Wednesday")
)
console.log(
  getDates(2020, 9, "Monday")
)
```

```js
/* Without the need for a dayName array but needing the month name as input

**NOTE** this was more for my own entertainment - the date constructor may fail on some browsers that does not like `new Date("Monday, August 31")` such as Safari
*/

const fm = new Intl.DateTimeFormat('en-US',{dateStyle:"full"}),
    days = [...Array(32).keys()].splice(1); // generate 1-31

const getDates = (yyyy, monthName, dayName) => {
    const mn = monthName.slice(0,3);
    return days.filter(d => {
      const [,dn,month,day] = fm.format(new Date(`${mn} ${d}, ${yyyy}`)).match(/(\w+?), (\w+?) (\d+?),/)
      return dayName===dn && monthName === month;
    });
};
console.log(
  getDates(2020, "September", "Wednesday")
)
console.log(
  getDates(2020, "August", "Monday")
);
```

Comment: YW - we normally expect some effort on the asker's side, but this was too much fun to pass up

Comment: I could possibly make one without the need for the dayName array

Comment: I'm using the dates  array to map them to their respective days on a timetable that has only the day parameter that's why I'm using the dayName

Comment: I revisited and my function did not return the dates. I also added a more elegant (but possibly less performant) version which however needs the Month name as input

Comment: I do not have numeric mn in the second example

Comment: Also I was sort of expecting some browsers not liking the verbose date constructor format